# Is every graph an incomparability graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, posets

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple, undirected graph. Is there a [partial ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) $\leq\subseteq (V\times V)$ with the following property? $$\{v,w\} \in E \text{ if and only if } v||y$$

(We write $v||w$ in the poset $(V,\leq)$ if $v\not \leq w$ and $w\not\leq v$?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any [incomparability graph](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870812001077) is perfect (shown by Dilworth in 1950), so any non-perfect graph will be a counterexample. For an explicit counterexample, choose the cycle on $5$ vertices.

Answer (score 6):

No and they are called incomparability graphs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability_graph

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you look at the complement, you have a "comparability" graph, in which every chain of the poset corresponds to a clique. It is enough to see that is a very particular class.